# Как выполнить функцию после ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax

В общем задача была заблокировать весь контент на странице пока она не загрузится. Сделал на всю страницу див, которому после загрузки присваивается display:none;

```
 <script>
    window.onload = function() {
        document.getElementById('blocker').style.display = "none";
    };
 </script>
```

Но возникла следующая проблема, когда я перехожу на следующую страницу с помощью ajax и возвращаюсь назад этот скрипт не выполняется и контент остается заблокированным. Как сделать так, чтобы этот скрипт выполнялся? Или может можно как-то по другому сделать?

Comment: Чтобы выполнить функцию после ajax - надо запустить ее после ajax. Найдите то место в коде, где текущая страница заменяется - и пишите код там.

Answer (score 1):

Почему бы не показывать\скрывать overlay при наступлении событий xhr, а не страницы?

```js
function getXmlHttp(){
    var xmlhttp;
    try {
        xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    catch(e) {
        try {
            xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch(E) {
            xmlhttp = false;
        }
    }
    if(!xmlhttp && typeof XMLHttpRequest != 'undefined') {
        xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    return xmlhttp;
}

var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');

var req = getXmlHttp() 
req.onreadystatechange = function() {  
 switch(this.readyState) {
        case 1: //Перед началом ajax-запроса
            overlay.style.display = 'block';
            break;
        case 4: //После окончания ajax-запроса
            overlay.style.display = 'none';
            if(this.status == 200) {
                console.log('Данные получены');
            }
            else {
                console.log('Произошла ошибка');
            }
            break;
    }
}

req.open('GET', 'https://openexchangerates.org/api/currencies.json?r=' +  + Math.random(), true);  
req.send(null);
```

```css
#overlay {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
```